# Show block of text that contains different font sizes and styles

Tags: ios

I'm working on an iPhone app and am wondering how can I show a block of text with sub-strings being bold and\or a different size programmatically. Seems like it should be doable, but I'm having a hard time finding an example or finding the right thing to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only option is to use a `UIWebView`.
Create your HTML dynamically using `[NSString stringWithFormat:];` and then you can do `[myWebView loadHTMLString:previouslyCreatedHTMLString baseURL:nil];`

Hope this helps.

Cheers!